# How to separate contents from NSArray into two new one in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

any one here have an idea how I could separate this array in to 2??

```
2013-08-25 02:47:47.052 yahoo[11357:c07] (
"",
"1377253260000.33300.0",
"1377253440000.33280.0",
"1377254100000.33280.0",
"1377255600000.33220.0",
"1377257400000.33220.0",
"1377261660000.33200.0",
"1377264000000.33200.0",
"1377264060000.33200.0",
"1377267780000.33200.0",
"1377271260000.33200.0",
"1377273120000.33200.0",
"1377273180000.33200.0",
"1377273240000.33240.0",
""
)
```

The first NSArray would be with the long numbers and the second with the smaller one including the ".".

So something like: array1 with 1377253260000 and array2 with 33300.0 and so on.

Comment: How about a quick `$ man sscanf`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what is that? is it objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of different ways of doing this. For example, you could do something as simple as find the first period, and add the string up to that period in the first array and everything after in the next array:

```
NSMutableArray *smallerNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *longNumbers    = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *string in array) {
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"."];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [longNumbers    addObject:[string substringToIndex:range.location - 1]];
        [smallerNumbers addObject:[string substringFromIndex:range.location + 1]];
    } else {
        [longNumbers    addObject:@""];    // or you could insert [NSNull null] or whatever
        [smallerNumbers addObject:@""];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way..

```
NSArray *objects = @[
                    @"",
                    @"1377253260000.33300.0",
                    @"1377253440000.33280.0",
                    @"1377254100000.33280.0",
                    @"1377255600000.33220.0",
                    @"1377257400000.33220.0",
                    @"1377261660000.33200.0",
                    @"1377264000000.33200.0",
                    @"1377264060000.33200.0",
                    @"1377267780000.33200.0",
                    @"1377271260000.33200.0",
                    @"1377273120000.33200.0",
                    @"1377273180000.33200.0",
                    @"1377273240000.33240.0",
                    @""
                    ];

NSMutableArray *firstParts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:objects.count];
NSMutableArray *secondParts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:objects.count];

for (NSString *object in objects)
{
    NSArray *components = [object componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if (components.count > 0) {
        [firstParts addObject:components[0]];
    }
    if (components.count > 1) {
        [secondParts addObject:components[1]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"firstParts = %@", firstParts);
NSLog(@"secondParts = %@", secondParts);
```